# How to run processes piped with bash on multiple cores?

Tags: linux, bash, process, scheduling, multicore

I have a simple bash script that pipes output of one process to another.  Namely:.

```
dostuff | filterstuff
```

It happens that on my Linux system (openSUSE if it matters, kernel 2.6.27) these both processes run on a single core.  However, running different *processes* on different cores is a default policy that doesn't happen to trigger in this case.

What component of the system is responsible for that and what should I do to utilize multicore feature?

**Note** that there's no such problem on 2.6.30 kernel.

**Clarification**:  Having followed [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)'s advice, I made *sure* with top program, that piped processes are indeed *always* run on the same processor.  Linux scheduler, which usually does a really good job, this time doesn't do it.

I figure that something in bash prevents OS from doing it.  The thing is that I need a *portable* solution for both multi-core and single-core machines.  The `taskset` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398588/how-to-run-processes-piped-with-bash-on-multiple-cores/1398659#1398659) proposed by [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) won't work on single-core machines.  Currently I'm using:,

```
dostuff | taskset -c 0 filterstuff
```

but this seems like a dirty hack.  Could anyone provide a better solution?

Comment: Try repeating your test with `top` several times (without `taskset`). When I did, sometimes the two processes were on the same CPU, sometimes different ones.

Comment: They're always on the same one and utilize only 50% of system :(

Comment: Try `( dostuff ) | ( filterstuff )` and see which core they show up on. One difference (if it matters) is that you're on a multicore system and I'm on a multi-processor (single core each) system. Why do you want to separate these processes anyway? Are they programs you wrote and can you change them so that they influence the scheduler themselves?

Comment: If they're serial (the nature of unix pipes) do you really get a performance boost if they're on different cores?

Comment: @Jeremy: yes, it runs 2-3 times faster on different cores: I measured this on `bzcat file.bz2 | gzip >file.gz`.  In the original case, `dostuff` performs costly calculations and yields lots of output and `filterstuff` archives it on the fly.  Data transfer is not a bottleneck in my case.

Comment: @Pavel Shved: See my edited post for an experiment you could try.

Comment: If this process really is faster when you force it onto two separate cores, then you should email this case study to LKML. Broken heuristics should be fixed.

Comment: @Novelocrat Is the place for this the LKML or should bash be able to perform the heuristic without kernel help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose `dostuff` is running on one CPU.  It writes data into a pipe, and that data will be in  cache on that CPU.  Because `filterstuff` is reading from that pipe, the scheduler decides to run it on the same CPU, so that its input data is already in cache.

If your kernel is built with `CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG=y`,

```
# echo NO_SYNC_WAKEUPS > /sys/kernel/debug/sched_features
```

should disable this class of heuristics.  (See `/usr/src/linux/kernel/sched_features.h` and `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_*` for other scheduler tunables.)

If that helps, and the problem still happens with a newer kernel, **and** it's really faster to run on separate CPUs than one CPU, please report the problem to the Linux Kernel Mailing List so that they can adjust their heuristics.

Comment: NO_SYNC_WAKEUPS worked.  However, the kernel is 2.6.27, whereas on 2.6.30 system the problem doesn't seem to arise.  I'll investigate it further.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it on 2.6.30.  Processes bounce between the cores both with and without SYNC_WAKEUPS.

Comment: Ok, I tihnk, this solves the problem.  Since my product doesn't have many users, and their kernels are compiled just fine, I can ask them to tune them in the way you provided.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try to set the CPU (processor) affinity:

```
taskset -c 0 dostuff | taskset -c 1 filterstuff
```

**Edit:**

Try this experiment:

- create a file called proctest and `chmod +x proctest` with this as the contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  while true
  do
    ps
    sleep 2
  done
  ```
- start this running:

  ```
  ./proctest | grep bash
  ```
- in another terminal, start top - make sure it's sorting by %CPU
- let it settle for several seconds, then quit
- issue the command `ps u`
- start `top -p` with a list of the PIDs of the highest several processes, say 8 of them, from the list left on-screen by the exited `top` plus the ones for `proctest` and `grep` which were listed by `ps` - all separated by commas, like so (the order doesn't matter):

  ```
  top -p 1234, 1255, 1211, 1212, 1270, 1275, 1261, 1250, 16521, 16522
  ```
- add the processor field - press <kbd>f</kbd> then <kbd>j</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd>
- set the sort to PID - press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd>
- optional: press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to turn on thread view
- optional: press <kbd>d</kbd> and type `.09` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set a short delay time
- now watch as processes move from processor to processor, you should see `proctest` and `grep` bounce around, sometimes on the same processor, sometimes on different ones

Comment: Amazing!  It works.  But, hm, why can't I evade manual assigning to cores?

Comment: See `man sched_setscheduler` and `man cpuset` for more information. Linux does a good job of scheduling. Try running `top` and press fj<space> to add the processor (P) field and you'll see that different processes are running on different CPUs.

Comment: You can also press `1` (one) in `top` to see the CPU load separately per CPU at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux scheduler is designed to give maximum throughput, not do what you imagine is best. If you're running processes which are connected with a pipe, in all likelihood, one of them is blocking the other, then they swap over. Running them on separate cores would achieve little or nothing, so it doesn't.

If you have two tasks which are both genuinely ready to run on the CPU, I'd expect to see them scheduled on different cores (at some point).

My guess is, what happens is that dostuff runs until the pipe buffer becomes full, at which point it can't run any more, so the "filterstuff" process runs, but it runs for such a short time that dostuff doesn't get rescheduled until filterstuff has finished filtering the entire pipe buffer, at which point dostuff then gets scheduled again.

Comment: Your guess is wrong.  The processes run like this: `dostuff` takes 60% of core's CPU time, and `filterstuff` takes the remaining 40%.  And they don't get rescheduled to different cores withing several minutes of running.

Comment: Fair enough then, just an idea.