# Fix Threads to execute on certain cores

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind threads to processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458811/bind-threads-to-processors)

In Linux, is it possible to fix threads to execute on certain cores. If that is possible, I also want to know if it is possible to execute one thread exclusively on a certain core, that is disallowing any other thread to execute on that core while that thread is executing.

Comment: It might be worth noting that it's the scheduler's job to assign threads to cpus in an efficient manner. Is there a reason you need to second-guess it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`pthread_setaffinity_np(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) does.

> The `pthread_setaffinity_np()` function sets the CPU affinity mask of
>   the thread thread to the CPU set pointed to by cpuset.  If the call is
>   successful, and the thread is not currently running on one of the CPUs
>   in cpuset, then it is migrated to one of those CPUs.

As an example:

```
cpu_set_t set;
CPU_ZERO(&set);
CPU_SET(3, &set); /* Run only on the third CPU. */

pthread_setaffinity_np(thr, CPU_SETSIZE, &set);
```

You can also do it with [`sched_setaffinity(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) and `gettid`, **but** that manual page says:

> If you are using the POSIX threads API, then **use
>   `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` instead of `sched_setaffinity()`**.